# Modify an existing to_char date format

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

Oracle SQL automatically converts my field D.START_DT to the following format:

```
TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Which makes it difficult for me to modify my own date format.

I've tried wrapping another `TO_CHAR` around it with no luck.

```
TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM/DD')
```

And I've tried `SUBSTR` to select certain characters, with no luck. I think the hyphen is getting int he way.

```
SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 6, 7) || '/' || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 9, 10)
```

What is the work around for this?

Comment: Are you able to use Oracle's [`REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) function?

Comment: So far I haven't been able to.

Comment: You can change the default format to whatever you want:  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=680596 Not sure what you mean by 'Oracle SQL automatically converts my field D.START_DT to xxxx'  If your field is a DATE type, then why can you pass it directly to TO_DATE function with the format you need. Please clarify your question and show the complete intiial SQL query you are tyring to execute.

Comment: Why: TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM/DD') ?  Why not use: TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'MM/DD') ?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator, because it converts `TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'MM/DD')` to `TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM/DD')`.

Comment: So whenever you try to use D.START_DT, it's automatically being converted to a fixed length character string?  What type is D.START_DT?

Comment: @OP - *what* converts it? Plain SQL, SQL*Plus, SQL Developer etc. don't do what you seem to be describing, so is there some other tool or environment you're seeing this behaviour in?

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator, That is correct. D.START_DT is a date type.

Comment: @Alex Poole, I'm using Query Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DATE datatype has no format.  When you see a date printed on a screen, there was something that APPLIED the format you see.  Could be a "default" in the program you are using (like SQL Developer) or your NLS setting, etc.  But, a DATE datatype has no format.  So, you have complete control over the format you see on screen.

The simplest is to use the TO_CHAR function:

select TO_CHAR(D.START_DT,'YYYY') from dual;

returns just the four digit year.

See TO_CHAR date format options.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA

You should always supply the format in your code and not rely on some other "default" to supply it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with RMAN Express and see no problems converting dates to any format you need... 
In case you still have problems try this (first to_char() in outer query is optional):

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(some_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM/DD') final_date
  FROM
  (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') some_date -- this is your "auto converted" date 
   FROM dual
  )
 /
```